# React. Failed to Compile Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-bootsrtap'

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am starting to learn React. I do follow several tutorials on youtube, but keep facing this problem when adding https://react-bootstrap.github.io/. I do follow all instructions provided on react-bootsrtap website https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction.

When I npm-start in console, I do see following message:

```
Failed to compile.
./src/components/Home.jsModule not found: Can't resolve 'react-bootsrtap' in 'C:\Users\Nikolay\desktop\testsite\nikolay\nick\src\components'
```

When I remove any reference to bootstrap from my code, it compiles fine.

Package.json looks like this (note that bootstrap is included):

```
{
  "name": "nick",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Please don't suggest running

```
npm install --save react-bootstrap bootstrap
```

instead of

```
npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap
```

as it does not help

Thanks!

Comment: in package.json file, remove ** from **"react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",** from both side and run command 'npm install'

Comment: can you please share your npm install --save react-bootstrap bootstrap log

Comment: ** is not actually in json file. I tried to make that line bold to make sure it is visible

Comment: @Muni Kumar Are you suggesting to run npm install --save react-bootstrap bootstrap log command? If so I am getting tons of errors

Comment: Looks like a typo in components/home.js if that is actually the message 'react-bootsrtap'

Comment: @Nick sometimes if you are installing node modules in VPN  it won't install. I just thinking about it. Check if the react-bootstrap folder and inside contents are available in node_modules folder

Comment: @MuniKumar react-bootstrap folder is inside modules folder

Comment: @Nick in that case, can you please remove the line in Home.js and re-add it some times vs code editor won't recognize.

Comment: I did run `npm install --save bootstrap` and it solved the problem! Thanks all for help and tips!